# Combining exposed filter with Facet

Tags: views, search

This is my big problem, I want to combine a field of free search (text) generated with an **exposed filter** and **facet filter**.

The main problem is the follow: if I do a search across exposed filter then facets are update regularly. (as it should be).

If, however, at the first filter the view with facets and then I do a search with the field exposed, the facets are reset. 
Is it possible combine facet and exposed filter?

Need some idea pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better is late than never :) you can use views with AJAX mode and my module [ajax_facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_facets)

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal >=9 see https://www.drupal.org/project/facets/issues/3013702#comment-14685036.
Facets 3.x (still dev) will have this functionality built in. It can then also be combined with better_exposed_filters for further customization.